# Persist periodic job run data in Nomad

Tags: nomad

I am doing POC of Nomad to run periodic jobs. It is very important that the history of job-runs is persisted. However, i see that when Nomad is killed, the job-run history data is lost.

Please suggest the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

use https://github.com/seatgeek/nomad-firehose and store it in a DB or Elasticsearch cluster

Ref: https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad/issues/4344